# How to disable graphics hardware accelerations in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, graphics, desktop-environments, hardware-acceleration

For troubleshooting purposes, how do I completely disable graphics hardware accelerations in Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa)?

The related Graphics settings don't seem to be available in the Settings app anymore.

Comment: If using nvidia see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689358/129111)